# Gitlab image with envsusbt and helm

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a problem with my GitLab job:

```
.render: 
  stage: validate
  image: alpine:3.7
  before_script: |
    function render() {
      apk add --no-cache gettext
        envsubst < $1 > temp-file;
        cp temp-file $1
        rm temp-file
        cat $1
    }
```

This job has a function, that will replace environment variable of the file given to it. The job is based on the alpine image, to get the **envsusbt** command. ✔️

This `.render` job will then be extended by other validation jobs, and one of them being a job for validating helm charts. ✔️

But the issue is helm is not installed on the alpine image. Do I have to install it? I would've preferred to use the `.render` job like a tool, rather than extending it. ❌

What is the best way for one job to have both the **envsubst** command and the **helm** command at the same time?

```
render-test:
  extends: .render
  stage: validate
  variables:
     ...
  script: |
    helm version
```

#### This job will fail, since helm is not present on the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was making an image that can have both the **envsubst** command and **helm** command. The image is `hamuto/tools:1.0.0`